# Find all solutions to the Initial Value Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

We are given that $u$ is the solution to an IVP with the following conditions:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt} = u_{xx} \\
u_x(0, t) = 0 \\
u(x, 0) = u_0 \\
u_{t}(x, 0) = u_1
\end{cases}
$$
We are also given that $u_0$ and $u_1$ are nonzero on the interval $[1, 2]$. And the task is to find all pairs of $(x,~ t)$ s. t. $u(x, t) = 0$.

I am having huge problems with this task, and, to be honest, with the PDEs as a subject in general, so I would also be very grateful if someone sent me useful materials on such problems and ways to understand this subject.

As for this problem, I tried finding general solution by applying d'Alambert's formula. However, found nothing useful.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You simply want to apply D'Alembert's solution. See here: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/4%3A_Fourier_series_and_PDEs/4.08%3A_DAlembert_solution_of_the_wave_equation

Comment: D'Alembert's solution only applies when the spatial domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$, but here the domain is restricted to $x\in[0,\infty)$. To properly adjust, you need to extend $u_0,u_1$ to even functions that are defined on all of $\mathbb{R},$ solve the extended problem, and then restrict your domain to $[0,\infty)$. Do you know why we use the even extension?

Answer (score 0):

With the Laplace transform, assuming $u(0,t)=0$

Solving the PDE

$$
s^2u(x,s)=u_{xx}(x,s)+u_1+s u_0,\ \ u_x(0,s)=0, u(0,s)=0 
$$

we got

$$
u(x,s) = \frac{e^{-s x} \left(1-e^{s x}\right)^2 (s u_0+u_1)}{2 s^2}
$$

with anti-transform

$$
u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{2} \theta (t-x) ((t-x)u_1+u_0)-\frac{1}{2} \theta (t+x) ((t+x)u_1+u_0)+t u_1+u_0
$$

Here $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside unit step function.